# Javascript not Alerting String Variable Value From Code behing C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

i am trying to alert string variable value using java script from code bhind my code is,

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ScriptDescription", "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('Error: Consultant '" + ConsZeroProj + "' projects do not exsist. Please select consultant having projects.');</script>");
```

ConsZeroProj  is string variable having value if i remove this variable it display alert  and when i append it . It do not show any alert what is the reason ?

hopes for your suggestion thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `ConsZeroProj` has some value in it?

Comment: Does by any chance `ConsZeroProj` contain `'` character? Probably you can also find an error in your browser javaScript console.

Comment: what is the value of ConsZeroProj ?  may be it  should be encoded?

Comment: it contains "PB Americas, Inc." value

Comment: i also tried by changing variable value to "STV" until then it is behaving same :(

Comment: Have you tried with `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ScriptDescription", "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('Error: Consultant ' + " + ConsZeroProj + " + ' projects do not exsist. Please select consultant having projects.');</script>");` note the `+`.

Comment: Please check my answer. It is resolved.

Comment: @All thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove single quotes wrapping the variable `ConsZeroProj`. Use the following code.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ScriptDescription", "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('Error: Consultant " + ConsZeroProj + " projects do not exsist. Please select consultant having projects.');</script>");
```

It is working, tested at my end.

Comment: my reputation do not allow me to up vote your answer when i will be able i will vote it up !